# Reassigning XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, mono

I currently have to iterate through a larger amount of .xml files and I am bound to Mono (so no brand new .NET LINQ etc.).
I use `XmlDocument` to load each XML file, now my question is, can I use one instance of XmlDocument for all files?

Code Example below:

```
filePath = "Assets/Units/";
        // Get all files
        string [] files = GetAllFiles(filePath);
        // And iterate through them
        xFile = new XmlDocument(); // create xFile once
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            xFile = new XmlDocument(); // or create it each time a new file must be opened / parsed?
            // do something
        }
```

Comment: if you are using C# you can use version 3.5 or newer and use LINQ.  It isn't from VS it is from the language.

Comment: really? I read everywhere, that you can not use that new stuff?

Comment: seriously.  Linq is direct from the language not from VS so as long as you are using .Net 3.5 or later then Linq is there for you to play with and enjoy.  I also think that it might make life a lot easier for you as well.

Comment: Yep, your information is plain wrong. Mono has supported C# 3, LINQ to XML and LINQ to Objects for well over two years. Maybe you are confusing LINQ with LINQ to SQL, which Mono only gained about a year ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be *cleaner* to create a new instance on each iteration. I'd declare the variable within the loop too. There's no logical association between the documents in each iteration, so why reuse the same object. I *suspect* it would work, but IMO it's harder to reason about. If you reference to the existing instance "leaks" to elsewhere in your code, the contents will suddenly be changing, probably unexpectedly.

(As an aside, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher I would strongly consider using LINQ to XML... it's a generally more pleasant API.)

Comment: Yep, `XDocument` should be available in Mono, too.

Answer (score 2):

In general it should not a problem to create a new `XmlDocument` instance for every file. I wouldn't do otherwise until you experience any performance/memory problem<sup>1</sup>. But if you get problems use a profiler first before optimizing, this will show you where the actual problem is.

```
foreach (string file in GetAllFiles("Assets/Units/"))
{
    XmlDocument xFile = new XmlDocument(); 
    xFile.Load(file);

    // do something
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>You possibly might see a benefit e.g. when re-using large array structures but I actually doubt you will see a benefit with `XmlDocument` as loading a new document will allocate new memory anyway.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about performance, and are not updating the XML files it would be worthwhile to consider using XPathDocument instead of XmlDocument.